# Calling order of base move assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the correct place to call base class move assignment operator from the derived class, as the first statement or the last statement, before return statement?

I have members in Base and Derived which needs to be moved as part of the move assignment operator.

```
Class Base {
    // Members goes here

public:
    Base &operator=(Base &&o) {
        // move all the members specific to the class here
        return *this;
    }
};

class Derived {
    // Members goes here

public:
    Derived &operator=(Derived &&o) {
      // Is this correct? Base class move here or below?
      Base::operator=(std::move(o));  // Is this the correct place??

      // move all the members specific to the class here

      // The assumption is that once we use move we cannot use the variable.
      // So, should I have base class move call here?
      // Base::operator(std::move(o));  // Or is this the correct place??
      return *this;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is correct for your semantic.
Normally it is correct to have default move assignment:

```
Derived &operator=(Derived &&o) = default;
```

Default implementation would start with base.

But if you are defining move yourself, there may be a reason, and this reason may dictate different order.

It may be even needed not to call base at all and do something entirely different. Such a need may come from the desired exception safety guarantee, for example.